# Multithreaded TCP listener with epoll and EPOLLET in C

Tags: multithreading, epoll, epollet

I want to write a multithreaded TCP listener using epoll and `EPOLLET`.

I have seen that there are several possibilities:

1. Each thread has its own epoll fd, does `bind()` using `SO_REUSEPORT` (but only up Linux kernel 3.9) and handles its own connections. `EPOLLONESHOT` would not be needed in this case because each thread handles its own file descriptors.
2. There is a main thread which accepts connections and several worker threads which handle those connections. Each worker thread has its own epoll fd. How can the main thread in this case fairly distribute the connections among the worker threads? It could add the file descriptor to the epoll fd of another thread using a round-robin fashion (but it might happen that that particular thread is still busy handling another connection). Or connections could be added to a global queue, and the main thread would use `pthread_cond_signal()`, but then we need a mutex and a condition variable.
3. There is a main thread which accepts connections and several worker threads which handle those connections. There is a global epoll fd, `EPOLLONESHOT` would then be needed in this case, so not all the threads get woken up for the same event.

I know that, if `EPOLLET` is used, once I get notified about an event, I have to drain the fd, until I get `EAGAIN`.

If the socket option `SO_REUSEPORT` is not supported (older kernel), which option would be the best?

Comment: Do you want your single TCP server to listen on multiple ip/ports?

Comment: No, only on one ip/port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5. A solution without using `SO_REUSEPORT` would be to have a common epoll fd and a common listener which are shared among all the threads. `EPOLLONESHOT` is required so only one thread handles the events for a certain fd at a time.

Answer (score 1):

4. A variation of 1. but without SO_REUSEPORT is to have a shared listen socket. Each worker thread run its own event loop, and in addition to handling its own connections they also do a non-blocking accept() on the listen socket. For a more thorough description, see e.g. http://aosabook.org/en/nginx.html

Comment: Is `EPOLLET` used in the listener socket? I guess in this case `EPOLLONESHOT` would be required, so only one thread wakes up when a new connection comes.